# How to remove Emoji from string using VB

Tags: regex, vbscript

I need to remove some emoji characters from a string using classic asp and vb script. Here is what I have:

Repeat / Other

Scheduled

Lead

And what I need:

Repeat / Other

Scheduled

Lead

I have been able to remove the emojis using this function but I want to keep special characters such as the forward slash /, spaces, &, :, etc.

Any help is appreciated.

```
Function strClean (strtoclean)
Dim objRegExp, outputStr
Set objRegExp = New Regexp
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = "((?![a-zA-Z0-9]).)+"
outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(strtoclean, "-")
objRegExp.Pattern = "\-+"
outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(outputStr, "")
strClean = outputStr
End Function
```

Comment: Try to remove all non-ASCII, `objRegExp.Pattern = "[^ -~]"`

Comment: Thank you very much, much appreciated. This pattern works in keeping all alphanumeric characters, objRegExp.Pattern = "((?![a-zA-Z0-9]).)+"  but it does not remove the emojis. Would I need two functions / patterns to get rid of the emoji?

Comment: Doesn't `objRegExp.Pattern = "[^ -~]+"` return the right result for you? Try also `objRegExp.Pattern = "(?:(?![ -~])[\s\S])+"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current regex matches any char but a line break and ASCII alphanumeric chars. It does not match emojis because VBScript ECMA-262 3rd edition based regex engine cannot match astral plane chars with a mere `.` pattern.

If you want to just add the emoji matching support to your current pattern, you can replace the `.` with `(?:[\0-\t\x0B\f\x0E-\u2027\u202A-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])` pattern and use

```vb
objRegExp.Pattern = "(?:(?![a-zA-Z0-9])(?:[\0-\t\x0B\f\x0E-\u2027\u202A-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF]))+"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FOZIfh/2)

If you just want to remove all but ASCII chars, you can use

```vb
objRegExp.Pattern = "objRegExp.Pattern = "(?:(?![ -~])[\s\S])+"
```

The pattern matches any one or more (`+`) chars (`[\s\S]` matches any whitespace and non-whitespace chars) that does not equal the printable ASCII chars.

Comment: The VBScript Regular Expression Engine was last released in IE 5.5 which implemented a non-standard JavaScript implementation JScript based on ECMAScript Version 3 not 5.

Comment: @Lankymart Interesting, do you have any reference where it is documented?

Comment: It's a bit of a trail, but [VBScript’s Regular Expression Support](https://regular-expressions.mobi/vbscript.html?wlr=1) explains how the last implementation was in IE 5.5 and you can trace the [versioning of JScript from there via Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript). ECMAScript Version 5 did not get used until the Chakra (JScript engine) which was implemented for IE9 and was call JavaScript but at the expense of any Active Scripting compatibility. Because of this it sat side by side with the classic JScript implementation that still uses ECMAScript version 3.

Answer (score 1):

One small change might be desirable to some. If you want to keep spaces, add a space after the 0-9 as follows:

```
objRegExp.Pattern = "(?:(?![a-zA-Z0-9 ])(?:[\0-\t\x0B\f\x0E-\u2027\u202A-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF]))+"
```